# Where is sourcecode of xen's credit scheduler

Tags: cloud, xen

Hello I am working on ubuntu with  xen's scheduler which is Credit Scheduler and I want to modify it. I have seen many research papers where you need to modify xen's credit scheduler but I dont know where to start. I mean I need to find source code of Credit scheduler so that I change it according to my purpose. Any suugestions will help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at section "Scheduling framework in Xen" http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~lu/papers/emsoft11.pdf , for location: find / -name 'sched_credit.c'